# How to send a request to Coverity web api using urllib2?

Tags: python, xml, soap, urllib2, coverity

I'm trying to send a SOAP xml request to coverity web api using python/urllib2 (I'm unable to install new python modules, so my options are limited to urllib2).

Below is my code:

```
def getDateTime():
   t = datetime.now()
   return t.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

def coverityRequest():
    dateAndTime = getDateTime()
    username = 'usernamestr'
    password = 'passstr'
    d = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v7="http://ws.coverity.com/v7"> \
    <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>' + username +'</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">' + password + '</wsse:Password><wsu:Created>' + dateAndTime + '</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header> \
   <soapenv:Body> \
      <v7:getSnapshotsForStream> \
         <streamId> \
            <name> abc.1.1_ab123 </name> \
         </streamId>  \
         <filterSpec> \
         </filterSpec> \
      </v7:getSnapshotsForStream> \
   </soapenv:Body> \
    </soapenv:Envelope>'

    r = urllib2.Request(url="http://x.x.x.x:8080/ws/v7/configurationservice?wsdl", data=d, headers={'Content-Type': 'text/xml'})
    u = urllib2.urlopen(r)
    response = u.read()
    return response
```

However I'm getting the below output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gen_release_ticket_info.py", line 49, in <module>
    output = coverityRequest()
  File "./gen_release_ticket_info.py", line 44, in coverityRequest
    u = urllib2.urlopen(r)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authorization Required
```

I ping-ed the server and it is reachable. Any ideas?

Comment: Push `Allow-Origin` header @maduranga-e

Comment: Can you tell me where can I learn about using coverity web api?

Answer (score 1):

That error code hints that it's looking for Basic or Digest authentication. urllib2 has an authentication interface.
PS The username and password aren't encoded properly in d. There will be problems if there are special characters like < in them.